# custom headers are not added to Request object

Tags: javascript, cors, http-headers, fetch-api

I'm trying to use `fetch` api.

First i create a `new Headers()` object:

```
var oHeaders = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication": '{"Username":"xxx","Password":"xxx","IntegratorKey":"xxx"}'
})
```

After headers is instantiated if i try to log headers everything is correct.

```
oHeaders.forEach(function(v){console.log(v)})
//logs: 2 application/json {"Username":"xxx","Password":"xxx","IntegratorKey":"xxx"}
```

the i create the Request object:

```
var oReq = new Request('https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: oHeaders,
  mode: 'no-cors',
});
```

If i try to log the headers of the request object only the `accept` header will be there.

```
oReq.headers.forEach(function(v){console.log(v)})
//logs: application/json
```

If i try to `fetch(oReq)` i get `401 unauthorized` response.

What makes the headers disappear?

Comment: So you are testing this in a script that runs under `https://eu.docusign.net/` as well? Or if not, why would you set `mode: 'no-cors'`?

Comment: i have to use `no-cors` because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The request has to be made from a different servers client side. I've tried to check the headers even without `no-cors` and the headers are still disappearing.

Comment: That makes no sense. _Because_ you are making a request to a different domain, it needs to have CORS enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `mode: 'no-cors'`for a request, browsers won’t allow you to set any request headers other than [CORS-safelisted request-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header). See [the spec requirements](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-headers-append):

> To append a name/value (*name*/*value*) pair to a `Headers` object (*headers*), run these steps:
>
> 5. Otherwise, if *guard* is "`request-no-cors`" and *name*/*value* is not a [CORS-safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header), return.

In that algorithm, `return` equates to “return without adding that header to the Headers object”.