# How to send JWT token with fetch and cors to an Express server in Authorization headers?

Tags: reactjs, express, http-headers, react-redux, fetch-api

I can retrieve JWT token from localStorage and send it in the `req.body` but for some reason, I'm unable to send it to the server with fetch() in `headers.Authorization`. I can log the token on the client-side but don't receive it on the server.

Client: React, Redux-Saga.

```
function* getInitialStateFetch(){

  var actionType = 'GET_INITIALSTATE_REDUCER';
  var path = 'react/listings28';

  var token = localStorage.getItem('my_tkn');
  console.log(token) // logs token

  var httpHeaders;

  if(token){
  httpHeaders = { 
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : `Bearer ${token}`
  };
  } else {
    httpHeaders = { 
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
      'Accept' : 'application/json'
    };
  }

  let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: new Headers(httpHeaders),
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  };

  yield call(apiCall, path, options, actionType);
}
```

apiCall.js

```
export default function* apiCall(path, options, actionType){

  try {
    const response = yield call(fetch, `http://blah/${path}`, options);
    const data = yield call([response, response.json]);

    // call reducer
    yield put({type: actionType, payload: data});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(`error api call for ${actionType}`);
  }
}
```

Server: Express.

```
router.get('/react/listings28', parserFalse, (req, res)=>{


  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3333');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  var token = req.headers.Authorization; // nothing here

  console.log(`req headers below`);
  console.log(req.headers); // no Authorization here
}
```

req.headers screenshot from the server

[image: req.headers screenshot from the server]

Comment: Remove `mode: 'no-cors'`. One of the effects of specifying `mode: 'no-cors'` is that it tells your browser to prevent your frontend JavaScript code from adding any headers to the request other than `Accept`,
`Accept-Language`, 
`Content-Language`, or `Content-Type` with the values  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506376/custom-headers-are-not-added-to-request-object/42506598#42506598

Comment: I tried without no-cors. Still no Authorization and it won't send the cookie.

Comment: Actually it still sends the cookie and it's no different with mode no-cors off

Answer (score 4):

Finally figured it out. Cutting to the chase - it won't work because for the browser to send the Authorization header it needs to have `mode: 'no-cors'` but if you remove mode: no-cors then fetch() won't even try sending the request from localhost but will work fine if I upload bundle.js to the server. Also you need to set credentials to same-origin if you want to send cookies, by default in fetch() credentials is set to omit.

So a workaround for this would be to use webpack's dev proxy so you use your server rather than localhost.